# 360 image viewer broken on IE8 and unable to debug

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, 360-degrees

I've been trying to debug the Expo360 jQuery 360 degrees image viewer on IE8 but unfortunately after many hours I'm unable to find the problem.

The 360 view works on IE11, Chrome and Firefox and can be viewed here: http://tinyurl.com/q3f38wb

For some reason, the entire product view is invisible on IE8 and using the developer tools and error console of IE8 I can't seem to pin point any specific error.

When debugging in Chrome there are no errors in the console so I'm really at a loss as to why this 360 image is not displaying at all in IE8.

The script is built and does work with IE8 though. I've extracted the script and I am testing it here on this page: http://tinyurl.com/mo9wqb6

If you view this on IE8 you'll see how it is viable and actually works well.

I'm thinking there may be a slight jquery error or conflict somewhere but without any details within the console I have no idea where. It could be as simple as CSS but again I'm not sure where.

Thanks very much for any help.

Regards,
Steven

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `position:relative` for the divs that you are using to load the 360 view images.